# || (OR operator) in JavaScript when creating jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, operators

Maybe I'm just too tired at the moment, but I can't find the reason why a plugin developer used the following construction:

```
jQuery.<myPlugin> || (function($)) {

    var $.<myPlugin> = {

        // plugin code goes here...

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Of course this is a common construction, except for the use of `||` (OR operator as far as I know), which I don't understand.

Can you tell me why the developer used `||`?

Comment: It only defines the method if it isn't already defined. If the first half of it is true, the second half is skipped because the expression is already true and doesn't need to go any further.

Comment: It's useful when you include the code more than once, defining the same plugin twice might cause problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would first check if `jQuery.<myPlugin>` exists, if not, it will continue to build the function.

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought of that, but I thought that it would be too easy to be something that simple. Or I just think too much. JavaScript is a little dirty, isn't it.